# H2 making one select from 2

Tags: sql, h2

I got 3 tables, Users, courses and course realation tables. I want to get users who aren't on specific course. So I figure I need somehow merge 2 selects with right join. How could I make one select from 2 selects?

```
SELECT ID, NAME, LASTNAME, ROLE FROM COURSERELATION JOIN USERS ON
ID_USER = ID WHERE ID_COURSE = ?

RIGTH JOIN 

SELECT ID, NAME, LASTNAME, ROLE from COURSERELATION JOIN USERS ON
ID_USER = ID WHERE ID_COURSE != ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract users for which it doesn't exist a record of that user for the specific course. You can filter the rows using a NOT EXISTS clause over a subquery.

Please try below query:

```
SELECT u.ID,
       u.NAME,
       u.LASTNAME,
       u.ROLE
  FROM USERS u
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM COURSERELATION s
                    WHERE s.id_user = u.id
                      AND s.id_course = 'YOUR_COURSE_ID_HERE' )
```